# Send an email using python script

Tags: python, email

Today I needed to send email from a Python script. As always I searched Google and found the following script that fits to my need.

```
import smtplib

SERVER = "localhost"

FROM = "sender@example.com"
TO = ["user@example.com"] # must be a list

SUBJECT = "Hello!"

TEXT = "This message was sent with Python's smtplib."

# Prepare actual message

message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

# Send the mail

server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
```

But when I tried to run the program, I got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python26/email.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "C:\Python26\lib\smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "C:/Python26/email.py", line 24, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SMTP'
```

How can i solve this problem? Any one can help me?

Thanks in advance,
Nimmy.

---

changed the name to emailsendin .py. But I got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\emailsending.py", line 24, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\smtplib.py", line 239, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\smtplib.py", line 295, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\smtplib.py", line 273, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\socket.py", line 512, in create_connection
    raise error, msg
error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: As a side note, don't create your modules within `C:\Python26`; make your own place for them.

Comment: Do I have to install an smtp server on my PC to be able to run this email sending program?

Answer (score 14):

You've named your module the same as one of Python's internal modules.  When you import `smtplib`, it tries to import `email`, and finds your module instead of the internal one.  When two modules import one another, only the variables in each module visible before the both import statements will be visible to one another.  Renaming your module will fix the problem.

You can see this, although it's slightly obscure, in the stack trace.  The `import email.utils` line from `smtplib.py` is calling *your* module, in "c:/Python26/email.py".

Another note: it's probably not a great idea to use your Python install directory as your working directory for Python code.

Answer (score 5):

Did you name your script `email.py`?

If so, rename to something else and the naming conflict you're encountering should be solved.

Answer (score 3):

You have managed to shadow the stdlib `email` module by calling your script `email.py`. Rename your script to something not in the [stdlib](http://docs.python.org/library/index.html) and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Does your computer also have an open mail server listening on the default port?
smptlib provides methods to connect to an smtp mail server, but if your computer is not currently running one, then you cannot send mail to it.